# reverseArrayInPlace() not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

There have been other questions about this problem, but I'd like to know why my code does not reverse the array given. Note: I am very new to coding, just teaching myself and trying to get practice for personal interest.

In the book [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#h_6xTmjj4Rf5), we are asked to write two different functions which reverse an array. The first function, **reverseArray**, is supposed to output a new array which is the reverse of the given one. That one is easy enough.

The second function, **reverseArrayInPlace**, is supposed to change the given array so it is reversed. It is assumed that merely using the first function and then assigning its value to the first array is "cheating". Also, we cannot use the .reverse method.

Here is my attempt, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(anArray) {
    for (var i = 1; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        anArray = anArray.slice(i, i+1).concat
        (anArray.slice(0,i)).concat(anArray.slice(i+1));
    }
}
```

Note: I don't like how I wrote this function, but nonetheless I can't decide why it doesn't work.

Here is the test code given in the book and the target output:

```
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The hint given in the book says:

"*The trick is to swap the first and last elements, then the second and second-to-last, and so on. You can do this by looping over half the length of the array (use Math.floor to round down—you don’t need to touch the middle element in an array with an odd length) and swapping the element at position i with the one at position array.length - 1 - i. You can use a local variable to briefly hold on to one of the elements, overwrite that one with its mirror image, and then put the value from the local variable in the place where the mirror image used to be.*"

I don't like my idea, but I like this hint even less. Is there something more in the spirit of changing the array "in place" with the hint's idea than mine?

Thanks for the help. And again, we can't just use something called .reverse on the given array.

Comment: is the body of the for loop one line of code? is the problem the double `.concat concat` from the first line of the body to the second?

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) Your code has a number of errors. But to get to the root of the problem, you can't just create a number array (which is what `slice` and `concat`) do if you want to change an existing array.

Comment: Each call to `.slice()` will create a new array. Seems like that goes pretty far afield of the spirit of doing the reversal in-place.

Comment: Now, this is how you ask a good first time question on SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not the shortest solution, I've tried to write it to be easy to understand.

Basically we create 2 index pointers into the array, left and right, with left of course starting at the first element, and then right the last one.

Because we don't need to swap the middle a simple check of left < right inside a while loop will make it stop before it gets there.

We then use the tmp var, to use as a temporary placeholder while we swap the items, after which we can increase the left and decrease the right index pointers.

To make this an in-place replace, we use index array access methods, using [] instead of slice etc.

```js
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(anArray) {
  var left = 0, right = anArray.length - 1, tmp;
  while (left < right) {
    tmp = anArray[left];
    anArray[left] = anArray[right];
    anArray[right] = tmp;    
    left ++;
    right --;
  }
}

var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

reverseArrayInPlace(a);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors:

First is that you have doubled `concat` call:

```
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(anArray) {
   for (var i = 1; i < anArray.length; i++) {
      anArray = anArray.slice(i, i+1).concat // two concats! one here and one on next line
      concat(anArray.slice(0,i)).concat
      (anArray.slice(i+1));
   }
}
```

The other error is that you don't return anything. The corrected function looks like:

```
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(anArray) {
   for (var i = 1; i < anArray.length; i++)
      anArray =
         anArray
         .slice(i, i + 1)
         .concat(anArray.slice(0, i))
         .concat(anArray.slice(i + 1));

   return anArray;
};
```

Note however that this is not even close to being an "in place" reversal. This code will make a lot of intermediate arrays before getting to the final result. A real in place reversal would be much different, probably swapping elements around.

Depending on requirements, one possibility could be to swap elements from the end with elements from the beginning, stopping in the middle. A swap will often consist of using a temp variable, which can be considered a violation of "in-place" as well.

To do it completely in place, even without a temp variable, it's possible to use an XOR trick to swap elements. This will only work with numbers, though, not things like objects. You also don't want to swap the central element (if there is one) this way, since you would zero it out.

```
// tricky way to swap two elements (assumes front != back)
anArray[front] ^= anArray[back];
anArray[back]  ^= anArray[front];
anArray[front] ^= anArray[back];
```

Comment: This doesn't modify the original array. It creates a new array.

Comment: @MikeC yeah, this is not an "in place reversal", but the question was "why doesn't this code work".

Comment: Right. It does not reverse the array in place. That's the part that isn't working.

Comment: @MikeC well, no, he said the part that isn't working is that it wasn't even reversing the array. the function is misnamed. corrected, it does now reverse arrays. that it's not actually in-place is important, but not a part of the actual question.

Comment: They said their solution which creates a new array is working but they can't get their in place solution to work.

Comment: @MikeC well I have now explained that it is not in place, have described how to go about doing it in place, and have given a small example. that is all I can do short of writing it for him completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working when you walk until the end of the array `(array.length + 1)` and when you return the **new array**.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var reverseArrayInPlace = function(arr) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length + 1; i++) {
    arr = arr.slice(i, i + 1).concat(arr.slice(0, i)).concat(arr.slice(i + 1));
  }
  return arr;
}

var r = reverseArrayInPlace(numbers);
console.log(r);
```

But the question is about reversing the **used** array with **other** **criteria**.

---

The hint in the book gives you almost the solution.

It's about

- swap
- half the length of the array
- array.length - 1 - i

A **swap** is

```js
var n = [4, 9];
var temp = n[0]; // Assign left to a temporary (locale) variable for a "briefly hold"
n[0] = n[1]; // Assign right to left
n[1] = temp; // Assign the temporary variable (left) to right
console.log(n);
```

Half the length of the array

```
var half = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
```

with `Math.floor`. It is there to catch also an an array with **odd** length

```
Math.floor(7 / 2) -> 3
```

**In total**

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function reverseArrayInPlace(arr) {
  var half = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < half; i += 1) {
    // Swap start
    var temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    // Swap end
  }
}

reverseArrayInPlace(numbers);
console.log(numbers);
```